# What packages do I need to install for DotNetty?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I've decided to use DotNetty **** they lack package support, they have around 8+ packages and I'm unsure which ones I actually require, they don't specify in their documentation.

- DotNetty.Common
- DotNetty.Transport
- DotNetty.Buffers
- DotNetty.Codecs

I know that it requires multiple, but I'm not sure which?
https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty

Comment: It seems that depends on which classes you want to use. Then add the related nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

As Janley Zhang mentioned that it depends on what you want to implement. You could get the [demo code](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/tree/dev/examples) from the github. 
According to  the **Program.cs** file, you could know what you need to refer.

And the packages also has dependencies, If you install the packages, **all dependencies also are installed**. **Take [DotNetty.Codecs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetty.Codecs/) for example**. For more information you could refer to the screenshot.

[image]